# Loki 0.4.1 packagekid process overloads the CPU

Tags: release-loki, cpu, processes

Please help me understand what is happening.
What is this process and how to get rid of the fact that it eats the CPU resource.
I will be glad to any help in this matter.

My laptop: https://www.asus.com/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_Flip_TP500LN/

Intel Core i7-4510U
nVidia GeForce GT 840M, 2GB
RAM DDR3L-1600 8GB
Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n
Bluetooth 4.0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added any third-party repository like a PPA? If a third-party repository has security warnings then this problem occurs. The related bug report is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1587975). You can see whether you have such repositories by updating the repo list from the terminal via

`sudo apt update`.

If you see any security warning like weak GPG-Key algorithm, that might be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The problem was in Skype For Linux PPA. 
Here is related issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/909312/skype-update-error-when-running-apt-update

After 
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
The problem is gone. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad that the issue is solved.